# How to call a function when receive push notification?

Tags: objective-c, ios, methods, apple-push-notifications

I am working on an iphone app with push notifications. My question is how to call a function from a classB when i receive a push notification without creating an instance of that classB nor using static method?

Many thanks :)

Comment: I don't know if you are clear about your Object Livecycles. If ClassB is an sigleton class then simply use that as an accessor. If you just want to call the Method in ClassB if any object of ClassB is in existance, then use the NSNotification mechanism, setting it up on ClassB creation and destroying it on dealloc. To cut this short: the livecycle of ClassB is the important part here to answer your question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to hold a reference to classB from within the object that receives the push notification:

```
// The header file of the class that receives the notification

@class classB;

@interface MyNotifiedClass : NSObject
{
    classB *_classB;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic, readwrite) classB *classB;

// The implementation file of the class that receives the notification

@implementation MyNotifiedClass

....

@synthesize classB = _classB;


- (void)theMethodThatReceivesTheNotification:(whatever)
{
    [_classB doSomethingNowPlease];
}
```

You will obviously have to set the instance of `classB` in this class before it will work:

```
// Someplace outside both classes (assuming _classB points to an instance of classB
// and _myNotifiedClass points to an instance of MyNotifiedClass)

[_myNotifiedClass setClassB:_classB];
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your help but however i didnt understand You will obviously have to set the instance of classB in this class before it will work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to call an instance method of a class without instantiating it. Your solution is either calling a class method or `classB` could have singleton initializer.